# How to use find_package when using cmake cross compile with tool chain file?

Tags: linux, qt, winapi, cmake

I use this tool chain to cross compile(from opensuse 64bit to windows 32bit):

```
# the name of the target operating system
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++)
SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER  /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-windres)

# here is the target environment located
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/i686-w64-mingw32)

# adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search headers and libraries in the target environment, search 
# programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Then use it like this :
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/zCross/mingw32.cmake .
But every time I try with this cmake file :

```
project(ut6)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

set(ut6_SRCS ut6.cpp main.cpp)
qt4_automoc(${ut6_SRCS})
add_executable(ut6 ${ut6_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(ut6 ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS ut6 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

this console out put is :

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:657 (message):
  /usr/bin/qmake reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as "/usr/lib64" but QtCore could
  not be found there.  Qt is NOT installed correctly for the target build
  environment.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:661 (message):
  Could NOT find QtCore.  Check
  /home/aked/projects/ut6/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

Looks like it is looking for the library on local system but not the mingw32 location,can I still use find_package when cross compiling?

right now I am just link with libQtCore.dll.a manually,it works,but when I want to use qt4_automoc to generate moc information,I am stuck again. thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution,Find qt4 just don't work when you cross compilling,you have to set everything manually with this:(inside toolchain file) (the directory on each system may not the same)

```
set(QT_BINARY_DIR   /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/)  
set(QT_LIBRARY_DIR  ${KDE_PREFIX}/lib)
set(QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY   ${KDE_PREFIX}/lib/libQtCore4.a)
set(QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR ${KDE_PREFIX}/include/QtCore)
set(QT_MKSPECS_DIR  ${KDE_PREFIX}/mkspecs)
set(QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE  ${QT_BINARY_DIR}/moc)
set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE  ${QT_BINARY_DIR}/qmake)
set(QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE  ${QT_BINARY_DIR}/uic)
```